# pass value of sub-array to key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array :

```
$arr = array(0 => array('id' => "AMO"), 1 => array('id' => "PAT"));
```

And I would like to obtain this one :

```
array(
'AMO' => array(),
'PAT' => array()
)
```

How could I do this, in the shortest way possible ?

I can do it with an array_map, followed by an array_flip and next an array_walk .. but too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) to extract the keys and [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys) to create the new array:

```
$arr = array(0 => array('id' => "AMO"), 1 => array('id' => "PAT"));

$res = array_fill_keys(array_column($arr, 'id'), []);
```

Comment: Yes ! I didn't know the array_column() function. Magic. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

simply loop over array and make its id to new array key

```
$arr = array(0 => array('id' => "AMO"), 1 => array('id' => "PAT"));

foreach($arr as $value)
{
    $new_arr[$value['id']] = array();
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/eXaAX)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is the logic behind this, but you can try this one.

Here we are using `array_combine`, `array_keys` and `array_fill`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/874225)

```
$result=  array_combine(
            array_column($array,"id"),//getting column id
            array_fill(0, count($array), array())//mapping that keys with empty array
        );
```

Comment: I like this solution +1

Comment: @Akintunde Thankss.. friend.. :)